# I want to replace column value with space instead of hyphen in my table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have tried this code. Please help me.

```
update city set city_name like '% %' where city_name like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly what you search. it replace '-' to ' '

```
UPDATE city SET city_name = SELECT REPLACE(city_name,'-',' ') WHERE city_name LIKE '%-%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE` function like this:

```
update city 
   set city_name = REPLACE(city_name, '-', ' ') 
where city_name like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> **REPLACE**(*str*,*from_str*,*to_str*)
>
> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string *`from_str`*
>   replaced by the string *`to_str`*. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for `from_str`.

```
UPDATE city
 SET =REPLACE(city_name,' ','-') 
 WHERE city_name like '% %'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi i wanted to replace '-' with ' '  please edit your code.
I have updated with 
UPDATE city
SET city_name = REPLACE(city_name,'-', ' ') 
where city_name like '%-%';

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE city
SET city_name = REPLACE(city_name,'-', ' ') 
where city_name like '%-%';
```